# Подбор алгоритма планирования потоков с одинаковой величиной кванта

Tags: python

Выполняю проект, основной задачей которого является воспроизвести модель планирования потока с фиксированной (одинаковой) величиной кванта.

**Теория**: каждому потоку предоставляется квант времени (постоянный), в течение которого поток может выполняться на процессоре. По истечении кванта операционная система переключает процессор на следующий поток в очереди. Квант обычно равен целому числу интервалов системного таймера обычно 10 или 15 мс.
[image: Граф процессов]

**Концепция:**

1. В системе создается поток, ему выделяется квант времени на выполнение.
2. Если поток успевает выполниться, то уходит из системы, иначе: по истечении этого кванта процесс прерывается таймером и помещается в конец очереди процессов, готовых к исполнению, а процессор выделяется для использования процессу, находящемуся в ее начале.
3. Поступает из очереди новый поток
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**
Правильно ли я понимаю, что данный алгоритм планирования соответствует планированию RR ([Round Robin](https://coderlessons.com/tutorials/akademicheskii/osnovy-operatsionnykh-sistem/21-kruglyi-algoritm-planirovaniia-robina)) и реализовать данную программку можно методом FCFS (первым пришел, первым обслужен)? И процесс, получивший в свое распоряжение процессор, занимает его до истечения текущего CPU burst. После этого для выполнения выбирается новый процесс из начала очереди?

Comment: 1) Вы бы давали ссылки на использованные материалы, раз уж прямо картинки приводите. И авторское право, и просто удобно проверять умозаключения. 2) Что-то 10-15 мс вызывает сомнения у меня. 5 мс кажется более верной для Python. 3) В простейшем случае должно быть так, как вы описываете, но дождитесь ещё комментариев. И я бы между стартом потоков давал небольшую задержку.

Comment: У вас на картинке есть ввод-вывод, а в том что вы пишите текстом этому вообще не уделено внимание. Поток может до истечения кванта времени запросить выполнение операции ввода-вывода, на чем планировщик должен поставить его в очередь ожидания ввода-вывода и передать квант следующему готовому к выполнению потоку. И пока данные из устройства ввода-вывода не придут такой процесс находится в отдельной очереди и не ставится в очередь выполнения. А ждать процесс может например ввода пользователя с клавиатуры, а пользователь пошел спать и значит потоку квант понадобится через день например

Comment: А так да, среди задач готовых к выполнению на процессоре (ничего другого не ожидающих) время можно распределять как вы описали обычным round robin, при условии что в системе нет понятия приоритета у задач

Comment: Спасибо большое за оставленные комментарии. Да, приоритетов у задач нет, достаточно просто реализовать данный алгоритм. Ещё раз спасибо всем!